# Launching an Android app from notification bar : Just after installation

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, push-notification

When you install an app from Google Play Web store through PC web browser on an Android device. A notification, "App successfully installed", will be seen on notification bar of the android device. I have seen for many apps (LinkedIn app e.t.c), a click on this notification will launch the app itself. How can I implement the same for my app? Any pointers? Currently, for my app, if I click on this notification it will open play store app and show the uninstall option. I dont want that :(

I searched for "launching app from notification bar", but it talks about creating an notification (pendingintent) and all. But in my scenario the notification is created by Google play services. So how to launch my app when user click on this notification "app successfully installed"?

Thank you so much,

Comment: This is not something you implement in your app. The notification is posted by the Google Play app, not yours.

Comment: But, I  checked couple of app likes LinkedIn. They have implemented that. I wonder how!

Comment: No, they didn't. The Google Play app puts the notification there after you download any app.

Comment: Question was how to launch the app when user click on that notification.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm telling you that YOU don't have to do anything, that's what happens you click the notification that Google Play puts there.

Comment: For me when I click on this notification, Play Store app gets launched, with my app's description and all (along with uninstall button). Not sure what messed up for my app. Any idea ?

Comment: Does your app have a launcher activity?

Comment: @Karakuri Just realized that is the reason. So if app does not have a icon, it will open play store instead of opening app itself. So I should keep the icon, right? there is no other way?

Comment: Seems that way. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if your application does not have an Activity that declares an intent-filter for the launcher, then the notification won't open your app and instead will open the Google Play listing for it.

I'm not sure what your app does, but most of the time you want to something the user can launch anyway. Reasons include:

1. Apps are in a stopped state after being installed and remain in that state until they are launched by the user. In this state, none of your application components will run.
2. Users may want a way to see what your app is doing and interact with it, even if it's just limited to configuring some settings. You can leverage this to do other things, like provide a feedback link.

If your app really isn't supposed to have a launcher activity, you could use `PackageManager` to disable the activity after they've opened it the first time.

Comment: Yes, In my main activity there is only browsable intent filter. Reason for that is I don't want  user to click on the icon and launch the app. I can disable the launcher activity after user open it for first time with PackageManager. Sounds like an good idea. But  then what happens to the icon (launcher), if I deactivate the launcher activity? Will that be gone too? If not, what will happen if user clicks on that icon at later stage?  thank you for your reply

Comment: The launcher application should update its app list and not show the icon any more. I don't know what would happen if the icon remained (my guess is it wouldn't launch anything), but that's the responsibility of the launcher.

Comment: What do you mean by app list here? Is it possible to update it programatically ?

Comment: I'm talking about the list of apps that the launcher shows, and no you cannot do anything to update the launcher programmatically. The launcher is just an application like any other. It learns about installed applications primarily using PackageManager. When you disable your own Activity, PackageManager broadcasts a change has happened, and hopefully whoever wrote the launcher application did a good job and will update their app list based on this change.

Answer (score 0):

The notification is displayed by Google Play app after installation automatically, for every app that is downloaded from Google Play, you don't need to do something special for it. :-)

Comment: I want to launch my app when user clicks on that notification. How to achieve that, that was the question.

Comment: As I know, the default behavior is that the app will be launched on notification click. There is nothing you have to implement.

Comment: No, as I mentioned for me a click on this notification opens the play store app with uninstall button.

Comment: Are you sure that you did click the "App successfully installed" notification? While downloading and installing your app, there is another notification "Downloading/Installing your app", which opens Google Play with app that is being currently installed I guess.

Comment: Yes, I am really really sure that I clicked on  "App successfully installed" notification. Is it because of some mistake in my manifest file ?

Comment: Hmm I am sorry, for now I don't know, what could be wrong. I think you cannot do anything about that, it is maybe some issue of Google Play, or maybe installing from website and installing directly from Android device makes a difference?